# Need help returning an array of everything in a table of a database PHP/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I want to return an array of everything found in a table of a database. The table has only 2 columns: id, and song_url. I would like the array to look like this:

```
Array {
    1 => songurl1,
    2 => songurl2,
    3 => songurl3
}
```

The keys are the **id** of each row and the values are the **song_url** of each row. I'm using PDO for this.

Thanks.

Edit (didn't see the edit button :s):

Here's my current code for doing this:

```
class Database {

protected $connected = false;
protected $dbh = null;
public $test = array();

function __construct($host=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $db=null) {
    if ($host && $user && $pass && $db) {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
            $this->connected = true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Could not connect to the database. Please contact an administrator.";
            $this->connected = false;
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        echo "No or not all variables are passed to the constructer. Contact an administrator.";
        $this->connected = false;
        exit();
    }
}

public function fetchAllSongs() {
    $q = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM song_directories");
    $result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result; // this returns an array, yes, but only 1 row

}

}
```

Also, the return in fetchAllSongs only displays one row (when I use print_r()), and not all of the rows. Why is that?

Comment: Posting what you want without showing any effort seems suspiciously like you're asking us to do your work for you. We generally expect people to try to work things out on their own and only post questions when they are truly stuck on something.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited my question. I haven't tried anything so far, but I suspect I might try what Paul answered. I haven't had much time to work on this more.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example on the [manual page for query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).  In the foreach loop make your array:

```
$data[$row['id']] = $row['songurl'];
```

Don't use 2 queries for something as simple as this.

Your edited code is very close.  Just change `fetch` to `fetchAll`, then rearrange the array as you want it.

Comment: Thanks. This is an extremely short and simple solution and works perfectly. I'm still learning some concepts, so I'll add this one to my library!

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 queries (one for each column), then use array_combine to create the array you want.

```
<?php
/*
$column_id       = // Get the ID column
$column_song_url = // Get the song_url column
*/

$result = array_combine($column_id, $column_song_url);
?>
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be unnecessary overhead?

Comment: @Nonym - Yes, but I do not believe that there is a solution to your problem without some overhead. I must admit though, looping through the results (as others have recommended) might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
$testArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<=count($rsArr)-1;$i++) {
    $testArray[$rsArr[$i]->id] = $rsArr[$i]->song_url;
}
```

Just to note: The danger here is if you have any repeating `id` values.